# How to fix container move up when click in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, scroll

I have header and sub-header on the left side container and I have text on the right side container.

Every time I click on the sub-header to show text on the right side, my both container position move up and it hide my header text. I'm not sure what causing that to happen so I would be really appreciated if I can get any suggestion or help.

HTML

```
        <div class="container-inside-dialog">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="primary-text header">Help Documentations</h1>
                <div class="column left">
                    <mat-nav-list>
                        <mat-expansion-panel class="exp-panel" *ngFor="let section of mappedSections">
                            <mat-expansion-panel-header style="align-items: center;">
                                <div>{{section.sectionName}}</div>
                            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                            <div>

                                <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let subsection of section.subSections"
                                    (click)="navigateToSubsection(section.id,subsection.id)">{{subsection.sectionName}}
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </mat-expansion-panel>
                    </mat-nav-list>
                </div>
                <div class="column right">
                     <div *ngFor="let section of mappedSections">
                        <h1>{{section.sectionName}}</h1>
                        <div *ngFor="let subsection of section.subSections">
                            <h2>{{subsection.sectionName}}</h2>
                            <p id="s{{section.id}}ss{{subsection.id}}" class="multi_lines_text"
                                [innerHTML]="subsection.text"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

TS

```
  navigateToSubsection(sectionId, subsectionId) {
    document.querySelector(`#s${sectionId}ss${subsectionId}`).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
  }
```

cSS

```
.dialog-container {
  width: 55vw;
  height: 65vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.container-inside-dialog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
 }


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  width: 38%;
  margin-top: 05px;
  position: relative;
  height: 530px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.right {
  position: relative;
  width: 62%;
  height: 530px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.button{
  width: 287px; 
  text-align: left; 
  padding-left: 25px; 
  height: 47px;
}

.edit-button{
  top: -50px; 
  left: 230px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Here is a picture of before and after clicking the subsection, I'm not sure if you guys can tell by just looking at the code above but if you can that will be so awesome. thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your global stylesheet try adding the following css. Sometimes due to page padding or margin issues this might happen.

```
html, body { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    
   }
```

***Hope this helps for you. Happy Coding***